# cordova-hot-code-push not deploying

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have my code (HTML, CSS and JS) along with chcp.json, chcp.manifest and cordova-hcp.json in the same folder on AWS. When I execute the **command cordova-hcp** deploy I get the error in the attached image

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I was passing incorrect information in **cordova-hcp login** command. I was entering my username and password for the AWS console, but it expected the access key and Access Key Id and Secret Access Key.